# C++ exit function from another function

Tags: c++, function, call, exit, infinite

I have created a class for the serial link with a read function.
I use boost::asio::read for reading data from the serial link. But the read function waits infinite until a byte has been received.

I want to create a thread that stops the read function if the maximum wait time has passed (because there seems a malfunction in the system).

Is it possible to exit a function in C++ from another function? Or cancel the read function call from the other function?

```
std::string SerialLink::read(const int maxTime) {
  std::string data;
  std::vector < uint8_t > buf;
  const int readSize = 1;
  try {
    buf.resize(readSize);

    //boost::asio::read waits until a byte has been received
    boost::asio::read(port_, boost::asio::buffer(buf, readSize));
    data = buf.front();
  } 
catch (const std::exception & e) {
    std::cerr << "SerialLink ERROR: " << e.what() << "\n";
    return -1;
  }
  return data();
}

void threadTime() {
  //This function will keep track of the time and if maxTime has passed, the read function/function call must be cancelled and return -1 if possible 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you do your reading in a thread (`pthread_t thread_read;`), then launch the timer in another thread (`pthread_t thread_timer;`).

After the desired periob, you cancel the reading thread (`pthread_cancel(thread_read);`)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to exit a function F in C++ from another function G?

No, but you could consider in body of G (called from F) [throwing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) some [exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions) (and [catching](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch) that exception in F, within the same thread)

> Or cancel the read function call

This is operating system specific. On Linux, you might use [non-blocking IO](http://www.kegel.com/dkftpbench/nonblocking.html) (and use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to detect when input is available, e.g. in your [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)). You could also use asynchronous IO. See [aio_read(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/aio_read.3.html) and [aio_cancel(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/aio_cancel.3.html).

Comment: Throwing an exception doesn't work in my case because function G is a thread function. And throwing an exception from a thread terminates the program. I don't have an event loop because the boost::asio::read() is the function that "hangs". And I don't want to alter the boost::asio::read() function.

Comment: You can catch an exception in the same thread that throwed it

Comment: Yeah, but that is not a solution to the problem because you still have to terminate the F function from the G function.

Comment: Actually, you probably need an event loop (so use `poll` in it on Linux)

Answer (score 2):

*If* `port_` is an ordinary file descriptor *and* you have POSIX available, you might first call [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [`poll`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) on it (the latter a little easier to use), both provide a timeout facility.

Device and OS specific (you'd have to read documentation), [`ioctl`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl) even might allow you to fetch *how much* data is available...

Comment: Good, but POSIX specific. I guess that  `select` is not natively available on WinAPI.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Truth, should have mentioned... [`select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select) *is* available in WinAPI, but only for sockets...